# Difference between .Value and .Text of a DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I would like to know the difference between the two.

When I display as  **VIEW** the result is - 12/27/2013 1:48:26 AM.
When I display as **TEXT** the result is- Friday December 27, 2013

Which is the better choice. I have been told that if date formats are different in pcs (for example one pc has **dd,mm,yyyy** and the othe pc has **mm,dd,yyyy**), the Datetimepicker may show error.

Comment: Ever weirder is that I have a DTP which is showing two completely different `Text` and `Value` values! `Value: 25/02/2019 13:00:00` but `Text: 25/02/2019 12:35`. That makes no sense to me whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DateTimePicker.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the DateTime represented by the control
`DateTimePicker.Text` is HOW the control shows its date to the user according to the [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

A `DateTime` value has no inherent format, it is just a numeric representation of a date. The way in which this numeric value is presented to the user is the Format of the date. This format is controlled by the regional settings of the local PC or the server. But it could be changed using various format strings.

Comment: So which is better in my programming as I pass data(from pc to pc through a network)? As I heard Differences in date format in different pcs could have issues

Comment: Which method do you use to pass this date?

Comment: For example I store the date in an access database from my home pc. But when I try to run the same program in another pc(with a different date format), it shows an error

Comment: Do you store your datetime value in a column of DateTime type? If you store in a text column then it is expected that another PC with a different understanding of date formats will experience problems to read back a string and try to interpret this string as a date according to its own globalization rules. Store it in a datetime column and you should not have problems

Comment: No just Text. I thought it might reduce issues

Comment: Sorry, but this is clearly wrong. Store always a date value in a column of datetime type, read it back in a datetime variable and then Format the value as you wish on the target machine.

Comment: So even if I store it as .Text or as .Value, it will be problem free if I set the database column correctly?

Comment: No, grab the Value using a datetime variable and store that variable in a datetime column. Do not use the Text property.

Answer (score 3):

DateTimePicker1.Value Will display your Current DateTime Value

DateTimePicker1.Text Will display your Format like Custom , Long, Short

Your default format is Long, that's why is showing **DateTimePicker1.Text** as **Friday December 27, 2013**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So can you answer the second part as well. How should I pass data between two pcs? Which method to use?

Comment: @ If you want to display date in Specific format go for DateTimePicker1.Text else go for DateTimePicker1.Value